# Which version of UglifyJS is implemented in Webpack 4.16.5?

Tags: webpack

Since webpack 4, the production output gets minified using UglifyJS by default. 
But which **version** of **UglifyJs** is implemented in **webpack 4.16.5**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version used is `3.4.3`, used with plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/master/package.json#L61

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit confuses. If webpack is using UglifyJS by default, It shouldn't be needed to install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin. Isn't it?

Comment: Webpack uses uglify-webpack-plugin which uses uglifyjs. Thats why. uglifyjs is present just on the plugin

Comment: I just installed uglify-webpack-plugin and run the build. The resulting bundle JS is 100% identical with the bundle JS before installing the plugin. It seems to me that you don't need to install uglify-webpack-plugin at all. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: No, you don't have to: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json#L30